# Pyspark - how to merge transformed columns with an original DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I created a function to test transformations on a DataFrame. This returns only the transformed columns.

```
def test_concat(df: sd.DataFrame, col_names: list) -> sd.DataFrame:
    return df.select(*[F.concat(df[column].cast(StringType()), F.lit(" new!")).alias(column) for column in col_names])
```

How can I replace the existing columns with the transformed once in the original DF and return the whole DF?

**Example DF:**

```
test_df = self.spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'metric1', 10), (2, 'metric2', 20), (3, 'metric3', 30)], ['id', 'metric', 'score'])

cols = ["metric"]
new_df = perform_concat(test_df, cols)
new_df.show()
```

Expected result:

```
|metric       | score  |
+-------------+--------+
|metric1 new! | 10     |
|metric2 new! | 20     |
|metric3 new! | 30     |
```

It looks like I can drop the original columns from the DF and then somehow append the transformed. But not sure that it's the right way to achieve this.

Comment: can you please share some sample data both Impute and expected output

Comment: @dsk I've updated my question

Comment: can you please check

Comment: added some screenshots for more clarity, check them pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it for many columns you would make a foldLeft call.

@dsk has the right approach.

You probably want to avoid joins in this case since there is no need to decouple operation you are describing from original dataframe (this is based on the examples you provided, if you have different needs in real case then maybe different example is needed).

```
columnsToTransform.foldLeft(df)(
  (acc, next) => acc.withColumn(next, concat(col(next), lit("new !")))
)
```

Edit: Just realised what I am proposing only works for scala and that your snippet is in python.

For python similar will still work just instead of fold you will do a for:

```
df = yourOriginalDf    
for(next in columnsToTransform):
       df = df.withColumn(next, concat(col(next), lit("new !")))
```

Answer (score 3):

I can see you have only adding a keyword in metric column , the same can be achieved using inbuilt spark function as below

The withColumn has two functionality

1. If the column is not present it will create a new clumn
2. If the column is there, it will perform the operation on the same column

**Logic to Concat**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F    
df = df.withColumn('metric', F.concat(F.col('metric'), F.lit(' '), F.lit('new!')))
df = df.select('metric', 'score')
df.show()
```

**Output---------**

```
|metric       | score  |
+-------------+--------+
|metric1 new! | 10     |
|metric2 new! | 20     |
|metric3 new! | 30     |
```

Comment: The idea was that there may be many columns in a DF and I want to apply a function to multiple columns. And then merge the transformed columns to an original DF

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new dataframe with updated column values and a `monotonically increasing id`

   `new_df = test_concat(test_df, cols).withColumn("index", F.monotonically_increasing_id())`
   [image]
2. Drop the list of columns from first dataframe and a `monotonically increasing id`

   `test_df_upt = test_df.drop(*cols).withColumn("index", F.monotonically_increasing_id())`
   [image]
3. Join the above 2 dataframes and drop the index colum

   `test_df_upt.join(new_df, "index").drop("index").show()`
   [image]